# Getting C error "assignment to expression with array type"

Tags: c, arrays, function

The goal of the exercise is to calculate a complex number Z according to some formula and create an array of n such complex numbers. Here's the function that calculates Z

```
double complex convert(double R, int p)
    {
        double complex Z=0+0*I;
        double complex A, B, C;

        A=exp(M_PI/4) + 0*I;
        B=cos(11*M_PI/6 + 2*p*M_PI) + 0*I;
        C=I*sin(R*M_PI/6);
        Z=A*((R*B)+C);

        return Z;
    }
```

The function that creates the array:

```
double complex *array_function (double *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    double complex array[100];

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       array[i]=convert(*(a+i),i);
    }

    return array;
}
```

And int main:

```
int main()
{
    int N, i;
    double complex *new_array[100];
    double array[100];

    printf("Enter the length of the array = ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("Element number %d is: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &array[i]);
    }

    new_array=array_function(array, N); // where I get the error message
    printf("The new array is: \n");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("%f + i%f \n", creal(new_array[i]), cimag(new_array[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting the same error message: "assignment to expression with array type" in regards to the line: "new_array=array_function(array, N);"

**Edit:** Here's the edited code:

```
double complex convert(double R, int p)
{
    double complex Z=0+0*I;
    double complex A, B, C;

    A=exp(M_PI/4) + 0*I;
    B=cos(11*M_PI/6 + 2*p*M_PI) + 0*I;
    C=I*sin(R*M_PI/6);
    Z=A*((R*B)+C);

    return Z;
}



double complex *array_function (double *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    double complex *array = malloc(100 * sizeof *array);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       array[i]=convert(*(a+i),i);
    }

    return array;
}

int main()
{
    int N, i;
    double complex *new_array;
    double array[100];

    printf("Enter the length of the array = ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("Element number %d is: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &array[i]);
    }

    new_array=array_function(array, N); // where I get the error message
    printf("The new array is: \n");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("%f + i%f \n", creal(new_array[i]), cimag(new_array[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new_array` is an array, and you can't assign to arrays in C.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth So what can I do instead?

Comment: There's another bug: `return array;` returns a pointer to local memory that goes out of scope after the return.

Comment: @Jens what do you mean?

Comment: @crylikeacanary Exactly what he said. Your `array_function` returns a pointer to the base of `array` within the function. The problem is, there is no `array` once the function returns, so the pointer is left "dangling". It used to point to something definite, but no longer does.

Comment: I notice that function `convert` computes `C` but then does not use it. Is there a typo in `Z=A*((R*B)+B);` where one of the `B`s should be `C`?

Comment: I mean that in `array_function` the `array[]` is an object of automatic storage duration. This ceases to exist when the function returns. If the caller uses that address, the behaviour is undefined. That's a **massive bug**. Never return addresses of storage with a lifetime ending at the return.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yep! Fixed it

Comment: @Jens and how would I fix that?

Comment: By not using an object of *automatic storage duration*, but of storage duration either *static* (`static double array[...]`), or *allocated* (`double *array = malloc(...)`). I recommend a good C book such as K&R 2nd ed and reading the comp.lang.c FAQ http://http://c-faq.com/ and **crank up the warning level of your compiler**.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin no, it's not intentional. Does it make a difference?

Comment: `scanf("%f", &array[i]);` is also wrong, you must use the `'l'` (ell) modifier for the `'%f'` *format specifier* to read a `double` (e.g. `scanf("%lf", &array[i]);`) which I suspect is where your crash originates since it invokes *Undefined Behavior*. (bad juju)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Okay, I fixed the int/float confusion. But that scanf change doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Does it still crash? What values do you input? Runs fine here.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, it doesn't crash. Now it prints 0.000000 + i0.000000 for whatever values I put

Comment: You didn't fix `scanf("%f", &array[i]);` it must be `scanf("%lf", &array[i]);` see the `l` (ell)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `11 * M_PI` is not an integer, and so the division by `6` is not integer division.

Comment: @WeatherVane - good catch, thanks. I'm always wary of whether macros are going to be typed right for that purpose.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: On this day of all dates, one ought to be aware that `M_PI` is not an integer.

Comment: Did I miss National Pi day again?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it seems there was an attempt to define π to be 3. Perhaps.

Comment: Yes, but that happened at the beginning of the month. I see the floating point aspect today. (I'll now have to convince myself `M_PI` is really a mid-month value `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign to arrays in C. You can only assign to **array elements**.

If you want to change arrays dynamically, declare a pointer of the appropriate type and assign the result of `malloc` and/or `realloc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have made the changes to insure you are reading doubles with `scanf` by adding the `'l'` modifier to your `%f` *format specifier* (e.g. `"%lf"`) and you have fixed your attempt to return a statically declared array, by declaring a pointer in `main()` to which you assign the return from `array_function`, and properly allocated the array in `array_function`, then your code should be working without crashing. Also, `M_PI` should be properly typed as `double` eliminating the *integer division* concern.

You must **VALIDATE ALL USER INPUT** (sorry for all caps, but if you learn nothing else here, learn that). That means validating the **return** of `scanf` and checking the range of the value entered where appropriate.

Putting those pieces together, you could do something like the following (with the code sufficiently spaced so old-eyes can read it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXC 100   /* if you need a constant, define one */

double complex convert (double R, int p)
{
    double complex Z = 0 + 0 * I;   /* space your code so it is readable */
    double complex A, B, C;         /* (especially for older eyes......) */

    A = exp (M_PI / 4.0) + 0 * I;
    B = cos (11 * M_PI / 6.0 + 2 * p * M_PI) + 0 * I;
    C = I * sin (R * M_PI / 6.0);
    Z = A * ((R * B) + C);

    return Z;
}

double complex *array_function (double *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    double complex *array = calloc (MAXC, sizeof *array);  /* allocate */

    if (!array) {   /* validate allocation succeeded */
        perror ("calloc-array");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)         /* convert your values */
        array[i] = convert (a[i], i);

    return array;   /* return pointer */
}

int main (void)
{
    int N, i;
    double complex *new_array;  /* declare pointer to receive return */
    double array[MAXC];

    printf ("Enter array length: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1 || N > MAXC) { /* VALIDATE ALL USER INPUT */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input or out of range.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf ("  enter array[%2d]: ", i);
        if (scanf("%lf", &array[i]) != 1) { /* VALIDATE ALL USER INPUT */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid conversion, array[%d].\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    new_array = array_function (array, N);  /* call array_function */

    printf("\nThe new array is: \n\n");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)     /* output results */
        printf ("  %10.6f + i%f \n", creal(new_array[i]), cimag(new_array[i]));

    free (new_array);   /* don't forget to free memory you allocate */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you should `free` all memory you allocate)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/complex
Enter array length: 5
  enter array[ 0]: 1.81
  enter array[ 1]: 1.97
  enter array[ 2]: .31
  enter array[ 3]: 2.51
  enter array[ 4]: 6.021

The new array is:

    3.43798 + i1.781127
    3.74189 + i1.881977
    0.58883 + i0.354442
    4.76758 + i2.121489
   11.43651 + i-0.024116
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I can't figure out what exactly was giving me the 0.000000 + i0.000000 result

Comment: I can, if you were still trying to read with `scanf("%f", &array[i]);`, you were filling `array` with *zeros*...

Comment: So what does the 1 if front of the f change?

Comment: It **modifies** the length of the value stored. With `%f` you are attempting to store a `32-bit` floating point number in a `64-bit` variable. Since the `sign-bit`, `biased exponent` and `mantissa` are encoded in different bits depending on the size, using `%f` to attempt to store a `double` always fails` (e.g. the sign-bit is still the MSB for both, but e.g. a `float` has an `8-bit` exponent, while a `double` has `11-bits`, etc....)

Comment: And **note:** this is for `scanf`. You can print a `float` or `double` with `%f` in `printf`, but if you are reading and converting to floating-point, then you must properly match the type by using `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`double complex *new_array[100];` declares `new_array` to be an array of 100 pointers to `double complex`. That is not what you want. You merely want a pointer to `double complex` (which will point to the first element of an array that is provided by the function). The declaration for this is `double complex *new_array;`.

However, in `array_function`, you attempt to return `array`, where `array` is defined inside the function with `double complex array[100];`. That declaration, when used inside a function, declares an array that lasts only until the function returns. If you return its address (or the address of its first element), the pointer to that address will be invalid.

The proper way to return a new array from a function is to dynamically allocate the array, as with:

```
double complex *array = malloc(100 * sizeof *array);
if (!array)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

… // Assign values to the array elements.

return array;
```

Then the caller is responsible for releasing the array at some later time, by passing the address to the `free` routine.

(To use `malloc`, `free`, and `exit`, add `#include <stdlib.h>` to your program.)

Comment: Ah, I see. That fixes the error but the program still crashes after entering in the elements

Comment: Okay, so now it no longer crashes. You can see my updated code above. Now it prints 0.000000 + i0.000000, which is not the result I want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the `array_function` create the content of `new_array`, you can send the array pointer as a parameter to the function, and let the function use that. You also need to change the definition of new_array to `double complex new_array[100]`

That is,

```
void array_function (double *a, double complex array[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       array[i]=convert(*(a+i),i);
    }
}
```

And in main():

```
double complex new_array[100];
...
array_function(array, new_array, N);
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it work like this either. It keeps printing 0.000000 + i0.000000

Comment: Now we are no longer talking about the subject of this question. However, I think your problem is in your scanf. You need to use "%lf" when scanf:ing into a double.

Comment: I know, is there need for me to post another question? I'm not really a regular here.
I changed that but I'm still getting the same result

Comment: Well, I tried your code, and after changing scanf("%f", &array[i]) to scanf("%lf", &array[I]), I got some nicely looking numbers instead of 0.0000.

Comment: Good deal. Good luck with your coding (and always validate all user input `:)`